# All positive integers $n$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k-1}}{a_k^2}=1$?

Tags: number-theory

How can we find the all positive integers $n$ for which there exists positive integers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ such that
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k-1}}{a_k^2}=1$?

My attempt:

For any odd $n=2k+1$, I guess that the solution will in this form:
$a_1=a_2=2,a_{2k+1}=4^k,$ and $
a_{2j+1}=a_{2j+2}=4a_{2j−1},1<j<k$.

For $n$ even, things get tricky a little bit.
For example for $n=2, 
\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{2}{a_2^2}=1$
this implies that $a_1,a_2>1$ but then $a_1,a_2≥2$ yields
$\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{2}{a_2^2}≤\frac34<1$. There is no solution.

For $n=4$, we can have the following solution:
$\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{2}{6^2}+\frac{4}{12^2}+\frac{8}{3^2}=1.$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There are solutions for $n\ge 3$. This can be proven by induction.

**Base Case:** For $n=3$, we have the solution $\dfrac14+\dfrac24+\dfrac4{16} = 1$.

**Induction Step:** Suppose $n$ is odd and there are $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ positive integers such that
$$\frac1{a_1^2}+\frac2{a_2^2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n-1}}{a_n^2} = 1$$

For $n+1$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac1{(3a_1)^2}+\frac2{(3a_2)^2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n-1}}{(3a_n)^2}+\frac{2^n}{(3\cdot2^{(n-3)/2})^2} &=\\ \frac19\left(\frac1{a_1^2}+\frac2{a_2^2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n-1}}{a_n^2}+\frac{2^n}{2^{n-3}}\right) &=\\
\frac19(1+8) &= 1
\end{aligned}$$

and for $n+2$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac1{(2a_1)^2}+\frac2{(2a_2)^2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n-1}}{(2a_n)^2}+\frac{2^n}{(2^{(n+1)/2})^2}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2^{(n+3)/2})^2} &=\\
\frac14\left(\frac1{a_1^2}+\frac2{a_2^2}+\dots+\frac{2^{n-1}}{a_n^2}\right)+\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n+3}}&=\\
\frac14+\frac12+\frac14 &= 1\\
\end{aligned}$$

thus concluding the induction. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions for $n=4$, found by brute-force search:
$$ \eqalign{
\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{4}{3^2} + \frac{8}{6^2} &= 1\cr
\frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{4}{4^2} + \frac{8}{6^2} &= 1\cr
\frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{4}{4^2} + \frac{8}{4^2} &= 1\cr
\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{4}{12^2} + \frac{8}{6^2} &= 1\cr
\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{4}{12^2} + \frac{8}{4^2} &= 1\cr
\frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{2}{6^2} + \frac{4}{12^2} + \frac{8}{3^2} &= 1\cr
}$$

I strongly suspect these are all, but I'm not sure.

For $n = 5$ I found a lot of solutions: $111$ of them where $\max(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) \le 100$.